# Accesing JSON response data via PHP

Tags: php, paypal, json

I'm using the Paypal API PHP REST SDK. I got a response that looks like in JSON format but i'm unable to access the properties inside the object and array.

How do I access the "state" properties from this JSON response via PHP? The response is being wrapped by the object of Paypal\Api\Payment type. foreach looping returns NULL

var_dump($response) looks like below:

```
object(PayPal\Api\Payment)#8 (1) {
  ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
string(28) "PAY-8JC052XXXXKKZMQNQ"
["create_time"]=>
string(20) "2013-12-19T10:19:34Z"
["update_time"]=>
string(20) "2013-12-19T10:20:38Z"
["state"]=>
string(8) "approved"
["intent"]=>
string(4) "sale"
["payer"]=>
object(PayPal\Api\Payer)#33 (1) {
  ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
  array(2) {
    ["payment_method"]=>
    string(6) "paypal"
    ["payer_info"]=>
    object(PayPal\Api\PayerInfo)#30 (1) {
      ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
      array(5) {
        ["email"]=>
        string(11) "some@email.com"
        ["first_name"]=>
        string(6) "fname"
        ["last_name"]=>
        string(5) "lname"
        ["payer_id"]=>
        string(13) "UAGGF3392CUTG"
        ["shipping_address"]=>
        object(PayPal\Api\Address)#31 (1) {
          ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
          array(5) {
            ["line1"]=>
            string(26) "Address"
            ["city"]=>
            string(13) "City"
            ["state"]=>
            string(8) "State"
            ["postal_code"]=>
            string(5) "000000"
            ["country_code"]=>
            string(2) "US"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
["transactions"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(PayPal\Api\Transaction)#34 (1) {
    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
    array(4) {
      ["amount"]=>
      object(PayPal\Api\Amount)#35 (1) {
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
        array(3) {
          ["total"]=>
          string(4) "1.00"
          ["currency"]=>
          string(3) "USD"
          ["details"]=>
          object(PayPal\Api\Details)#36 (1) {
            ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
            array(1) {
              ["subtotal"]=>
              string(4) "1.00"
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["description"]=>
      string(33) "Item name: 1"
      ["item_list"]=>
      object(PayPal\Api\ItemList)#37 (1) {
        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
        array(1) {
          ["items"]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            object(PayPal\Api\Item)#38 (1) {
              ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
              array(4) {
                ["name"]=>
                string(20) "Item name"
                ["price"]=>
                string(4) "1.00"
                ["currency"]=>
                string(3) "USD"
                ["quantity"]=>
                string(1) "1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      ["related_resources"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        object(PayPal\Api\RelatedResources)#40 (1) {
          ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
          array(1) {
            ["sale"]=>
            object(PayPal\Api\Sale)#42 (1) {
              ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
              array(7) {
                ["id"]=>
                string(17) "5DH04XXX63X"
                ["create_time"]=>
                string(20) "2013-12-19T10:19:34Z"
                ["update_time"]=>
                string(20) "2013-12-19T10:20:38Z"
                ["state"]=>
                string(9) "completed"
                ["amount"]=>
                object(PayPal\Api\Amount)#44 (1) {
                  ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
                  array(2) {
                    ["total"]=>
                    string(4) "1.00"
                    ["currency"]=>
                    string(3) "USD"
                  }
                }
                ["parent_payment"]=>
                string(28) "PAY-8JC05XXXXKZMQNQ"
                ["links"]=>
                array(3) {
                  [0]=>
                  object(PayPal\Api\Links)#46 (1) {
                    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
                    array(3) {
                      ["href"]=>
                      string(65) "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5DHXX91763X"
                      ["rel"]=>
                      string(4) "self"
                      ["method"]=>
                      string(3) "GET"
                    }
                  }
                  [1]=>
                  object(PayPal\Api\Links)#47 (1) {
                    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
                    array(3) {
                      ["href"]=>
                      string(72) "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/5DHXXA691763X/refund"
                      ["rel"]=>
                      string(6) "refund"
                      ["method"]=>
                      string(4) "POST"
                    }
                  }
                  [2]=>
                  object(PayPal\Api\Links)#48 (1) {
                    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
                    array(3) {
                      ["href"]=>
                      string(79) "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8JC052914XX1034SKKZMQNQ"
                      ["rel"]=>
                      string(14) "parent_payment"
                      ["method"]=>
                      string(3) "GET"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
["links"]=>
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(PayPal\Api\Links)#49 (1) {
    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PPModel":private]=>
    array(3) {
      ["href"]=>
      string(79) "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8JC0XX914D601034SKKZMQNQ"
      ["rel"]=>
      string(4) "self"
      ["method"]=>
      string(3) "GET"
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

I tried json_decode($response) but it returned NULL so i assumed that this is already the correct JSON format.

I tried echo $response->id and it returns blank

I've also tried multiple variations of foreach ($response->id as $value) { var_dump($value); } which also returns nothing

Help!

Comment: Post your foreach loop & the json to object conversion code. Also I will suggest you to convert your json object to an array rather than an object.

Comment: @Rikesh I've updated the questions with examples that i tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is not a standard JSON format. For some reason the Paypal API SDK return it in their own "json" format through this line

```
$ret->fromJson($json);
return $ret;
```

I just skipped that and return $json instead and it gives me the format that i can put into json_decode for further processing.

```
return $json;
```

That took me 1 full freaking day! Pff...

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? where did you skipped that lines? I am also trying to convert the data to json but still no success.

Answer (score 2):

If you use only **json_decode($result)** it will not convert entire objects into an array.
So simply use

```
$result=json_decode($result, true, 512);
```

It will convert all the objects into associative array recursively.
Try it. It works for me.

Comment: Please refer to this link first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) [Second Link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
$response->toJSON();
```

then you can use

```
$result = json_decode($response);
echo ($result->state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert json to a string then store the content in an array (decode it with json_decode).

Comment: I tried to json_decode the response but it returns NULL. Is it because this is not a proper JSON format?